# Copying a file in the Flask application folder knowing its web path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I have generated a web path of a file using:

```
URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Later, with an ajax call, I passed that link to Python (Flask).
Now, I'm curious to know how to use that link to copy the file into a folder of the application I'm developing. Using Python.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Why can't you just upload the file itself?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not a great expert. It is very recently that I develop web applications. I would like to take the file referring to this link and copy it using Python in the _static_ directory of Flask. It's possible?

Comment: File uploads are very common. Do some research into how to process them

Comment: Yes, I saw. There are myriads of examples, from which I took inspiration to complete the part of javascript. But now how can I get that file, knowing the link generated via `URL.createObjectURL (event.target.files[0])` and copy it to my application folder? Do I have to use another way to get that file through javascript and pass it to python, or is there a way to process that link with python / flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the experience I had, I realized that it is better to send the files with a specific call. Personally with JavaScript I got the files as follows:

```
const filePdfUploaded = document.querySelector('input[id="uploadFilePdf"]');
const fileTxtUploaded = document.querySelector('input[id="uploadFileTxt"]');

const filesUploaded = new FormData();
filesUploaded.append('pdf', filePdfUploaded.files[0]);
filesUploaded.append('txt', fileTxtUploaded.files[0]);

fetch('/documents', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: filesUploaded /* posting */
});
```

On the server side, Flask provides as follows:

```
@app.route('/documents', methods= ['POST'])
def addUploadedFiles():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.files['pdf'].save(os.path.join(app.instance_path[:-9],   #this
                                               'static',                 #concerns
                                               'data',                   #the destination
                                               'documentazione Tot Pdf', #path
                                               secure_filename(request.files['pdf'].filename)))

        request.files['txt'].save(os.path.join(app.instance_path[:-9],   #this 
                                               'static',                 #concerns
                                               'data',                   #the destination
                                               'documentazione txt',     #path 
                                               secure_filename(request.files['txt'].filename)))
        return ''
```

In this way the files are received and can be saved in a folder of the current project.
I hope I have been helpful.